# Cant turn off SSL

Tags: php, ssl, wampserver, dreamweaver

I am working on an old website (created in 2008) which is functional on its production site but has developed an issue on my localhost server. I can call up the localhost address of a page when the URL is entered directly into the browser address bar, but if I attempt to call it up through Dreamweaver, it attempts to render it using SSL, and the browser throws a cannot connect error. Something, somewhere, is forcing a SSL connection. Localhost is not set up for SSL nor do I want to do so.

I do my work in Adobe Dreamweaver v. 10.0, Build 4117, and a local server using WampServer. I recently installed a different version of WampServer after experiencing an anomaly in version 3.2.3 which made it inconvenient to use. This issue appeared after I uninstalled version 3.2.3 and installed version 3.0.6. I chose this WampServer version because the local setup needs php 5.6 to be compatible with the production site. I confirmed that all Visual C++ packages are installed correctly and feel reasonably comfortable that WampServer installed correctly. Prior to this problem, I used the WampServer/Dreamweaver combination for years without any serious issues.

WampServer’s localhost page is not accessible, but phpMyAdmin is functional. McAfee Antivirus is installed but has never been an issue. There is no third party firewall installed.

The website has several .htaccess file and I checked them and confirmed that they are not configured for secure connections. Adding the site to my virtual host settings did not resolve the problem, and relevant httpd.config ssl settings are commented out.

Where do we go from here?

Windows version: Windows 10 Pro x64,
Version 20H2,
Installed on    ‎8/‎11/‎2020,
OS build    19042.1237;

WampServer Version: 3.0.6 x64;

Apache Version: 2.4.23;

PHP Version: 5.6.40;

MySQL Version: 5.7.3;

Adobe Dreamweaver v. 10.0, Build 4117.

Comment: So just using chrome and not dreamweaver, you can goto the localhost website ok (not https)? And/Or does using a self signed cert on localhost correct the dreamweaver issue?

Comment: To your first question, that is correct. Bypassing Dreamweaver does bypass the problem. As to the second question, I have not set up the local site to use a self-signed certificate, but I assume that would "fix" the problem. However, this has never been necessary before, and it seems unnecessary to do so now if we can determine the cause.

Comment: I dont see any reason to Downgrade WAMPServer, I suggest always keeping up to date with that. You do realise that you can install pretty much any version of PHP/MYSQL/APACHE/ into all versions of WAMPServer3. As you seem to agree this is not a WAMPServer issue.

Comment: Did you create a Virtual Host for this site you are dealing with?

Comment: I posted this query to the WampServer forum and the response was that WampServer has no bearing on the problem. See, http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,162332. Also, the reason I I went with WampServer 2.0.6 was Twofold. First, it had PHP 5.6 already included which made it match the production website. Second, the version of phpMyAdmin included with the latest WampServer requires PHP 7.1. Therefore, I had to switch versions of PHP whenever I went from PHP development to checking the database and then switch back when I returned to PHP.

Comment: Yes, I did set up a Virtual Host, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Sounds more and more like a Chrome thing

Comment: Well, this is a mystery. I have been using Firefox and Chrome to do my tests. I decided to add Internet Explorer and Edge to the other two. Firefox failed to connect to on of the two pages I tested, but all of the other three worked correctly. I cleared the Firefox cache and, in a second text, it ran correctly too. So, by doing virtually nothing, the problem is solved. Thank you for your help.